# Finding embedded document without _id in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to find an answer on an issue that is keeping me busy for days. I would like to find and or update an embedded document in a MongDB collection (using mongoose). It is possible I know. You can do something like this:

```
User.findOne({_id: id}, function(err, user) {
var embeddedDoc = user.embeddedDocs.id('embeddedDocId');
});
```

This works indeed. However, only if you have the specific docId which I do not know (the embedded doc can be an item(x) of an array).

My question is, is this possible anyway? Or does mongodb not let us find an embedded doc without supplying an Id?

Regards, Douwe.

Comment: You can `find` nearly anything ... if you supply the right query. I don't understand what you're looking for. If you don't have the embedded doc id, how are you going to find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.
Use the dot notation to specify the property of the embedded document you are looking for.
Let's say you have a collection for persons with docs like this:

```
{
  _id:123,
  name:"john",
  address: {
      Street:"any", 
      zip:1234
    }
}
```

Then you can find a person querying by an address field like this:

```
db.persons.find("address.zip":1234, ...)
```

Just consider that it won't give you only the embedded doc, but the entire document (person in this case)